# Mongoose schema wouldn't call middleware to hash password

Tags: node.js, mongoose, password-encryption

My Mongoose schema looks like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import argon2 from 'argon2';
import argonConfigs from '../configs/argon-configs';

const { Schema } = mongoose;
const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  googleID: String,
  twitterID: String,
  emails: [String],
  hasPicture: Boolean,
  signupToken: String,
  token: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  console.log('inside pre');
  if (this.password) {
    console.log('this.password', this.password);
    this.password = await argon2.hash(password, argonConfigs);
  }
  next();
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

I amusing this schema to update records in my collection like this:

```
import User from '../models/user';

export const tokenInDB = async (token, email) => {
  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ token: token, emails: email, password : { $exists : false } });
  return existingUser;
};

export const createAccount = async (fname, lname, uname, pass, existingUser) => {
  let fieldsToUpdate = {};
  if(fname) { fieldsToUpdate.firstName = fname }
  if(lname) { fieldsToUpdate.lastName = lname }
  if(uname) { fieldsToUpdate.username = uname }
  if(pass) { fieldsToUpdate.password = pass }
  const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: existingUser._id}, {...fieldsToUpdate, $unset: {token: 1}}, {new: true});
  return updatedUser;
};
```

I'm expecting the middleware (`userSchema.pre()`) to kick in every time the update is made. This middleware should then use the `argon2i` library to hash the plaintext password entered by the user.

However, the middleware refuses to get called. The `console.log()` inside the function remains uncalled. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `createAccount` function, you used [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) and this function just trigger `findOneAndUpdate` middleware, not `save` middleware so the `console.log` not reached.

You can solve your problem by:

- Option 1: use `findOne()` or `findById()` to find the user, change its fields and then call `save()`. It will trigger your `save` middleware.
- Option 2: register the `findOneAndUpdate` middleware and hash your password in it but note that, `findOneAndUpdate` is **query middleware** so `thís` will refer to the query, not to the document like in `save` middleware.